# Smarty {if $foo} equivalent to isset()

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

Is there a way to change the smarty core `{if $foo}` so that it uses the `isset()` and `$foo|default:$foo2`?

The reason I ask this is because I am getting PHP warning messages.

I understand that I can do {if isset($foo)} although it is a lot clean to write this without the isset().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

within an {if} the expression should not throw any notices. (at least that was the case once)

you could write a simple [prefilter](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/advanced.features.prefilters.tpl) that (with regular expressions) looks for "{if $foo}" and converts it to the equivalent `{if !empty($foo)}`.

If you feel you've hit a bug / need an enhancement, share your thoughts on the [bug tracker](http://code.google.com/p/smarty-php/issues/list).